# Recursive listing files in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, directory

Here is my problem : I have a directory with 50k+ files and with a ton of subdirectories.

I would like to list all the files that have been modified today or this week, ordered by last modified date.

So I made a little script, but I always have a max execution time of 30 seconds (I think there's too many files). 
I'd like to have less than 10 seconds because it's a script I will display to users in a backend interface.

What do you think about this ?

Thank you very much by advance and have a good day ! :)

```
$out = array();
$today = time() - 3600 * 24;
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/filepath/'));
$files = iterator_to_array($it, true);

if ($files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_file($file)) {
            $date = filemtime($file);

            if ($date >= $today) {
                $out[] = array(
                     'path'     => $file, 
                     'date'     => $date
                );
            }
     }
}

$sort = array();
foreach ($out as $k => $file) 
    $sort['date'][$k] = $out['date'];

array_multisort($sort['date'], SORT_DESC, $out);

var_dump($out);
```

Comment: What do you want us to do? optimize your code? If so, this isn't the place for it. If you have a specific problem, then please clarify a question.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Might be *barely* faster to use `glob()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and iterate using a standard `for` loop, although I suspect the bottleneck is probably the call to `filemtime()` 50k+ times.

Comment: If your system is linux, it would be MUCH faster to use `exec` and run `find`.